# Compiling drivers for armada 370

Tags: linux, drivers, compiling, embedded, autoconf

I am trying to compile usb_serial drivers for a Mirabox with armada 370.

I first tried as followes :

1. Install linux source for 3.2 (running kernel is 3.2.36)
2. Install linux headers for 3.2
3. Edit the makefiles, version = 3, patchlevel = 2, subversion was 0, i edited it to 36.
4. I copyied the files from linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common to linux-headers-3.2.0.4
5. Then I copyied the usb-serial.c, options.c, qcserial.c, and serial.h, and usb_wwan.c to a subdirectory in linux-headers-3.2.0-4. Subdirectory is drivers/usb/serial
6. The makefile already exists there
7. I now cd to the linux-source-3.2, and run `make oldconfig` , followed my `make prepare`, `make scripts`, and finally `make distclean`
8. Then I come back to the header directory, and run `make M=drivers/usb/serial`

However, I am being greeted with the message, that include/generated/autoconf.h or include/linux/auto.conf does not exist.

So I checked, the first exists, the later does not.

How can I get auto.conf to exist? Should I copy it form somewhere? The header files specially in a ffolder called linux-headers-3.2.0-4-omap has this.

Please help.

PS : build essencials, automake, etc already installed.
Seemingly, autocong should be generated in a compilation step. which one?

Comment: I can't help much, but I don't think `autoconf.h` is generated (although it's name may suggest it). It's part of `linux-headers /usr/lib/modules/3.16.2-1-ARCH/build/include/generated/autoconf.h` on my system.